# Importing GeoPt data with the Google AppEngine BulkLoader YAML

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am uploading data from a csv file with a GeoPt column in it.  I have the GeoPt column data in quotes like this: SomeData,"54.321,-123.456",MoreData

My bulkloader.yaml file has an entry like this:
    - property: location
      external_name: LOCATION
      # Type: GeoPt Stats: 1 properties of this type in this kind.

When I do the upload and go to the DataStore viewer I see the location has been uploaded as a string instead of a GeoPt.  I'm not sure what the proper way to import this would be.  Perhaps it requires an import_transform?

Answer (score 4):

Create a `uploadutil.py` file and add this method in it:

```
def geo_converter(geo_str):
    if geo_str:
        lat, lng = geo_str.split(',')
        return db.GeoPt(lat=float(lat), lon=float(lng))
    return None
```

Then add this in `bulkloader.yaml`:

Add import for uploadutil:

```
- import: uploadutil
```

And add property:

```
- property: location
      external_name: LOCATION
      import_transform: uploadutil.geo_converter
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get `NameError global name 'db' is not defined` while uploading data, add line

```
 from google.appengine.ext import db
```

to file uploadutil.py